# Reload entire page without refreshing once with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

How do I silently reload the current page(the body or all of it) without refreshing? I only want to reload the page once in a callback javascript function. This is because some data has changed.

EDIT: To clarify, I want to reload/refresh the page without the user seeing it noticeably refresh besides the content changing. I'm a beginner so if I were to use Ajax where do I put it? Currently I have a .js javascript file with all my functions.

Comment: Maybe you're after a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)...

Comment: How is reloading an entire page (functionally) different from refreshing?

Comment: Do you mean refresh the page without reload?

Comment: If you want to refresh the page without reload, you would use AJAX

Comment: 2 possibility.. ajax? or javascript reload page: location.reload();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a div content *or change it* based on user input, you should use jquery and ajax...
By example I will show you a script that will change the body of a webpage by clicking on the nav menu without reloading the page.

```
function navnewtab(){
            b='';
            $('.ocultar').hide()
            console.log("clicked!");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'script/tabclickhandler.php',
                data: {'somepostvariable':'value',
                       'somepostvariable2': value_that_can_be_a_javascript_variable_passed_on_function},
                success: function(data) {
                     console.log("post results");
                    console.log(data); ///post results data
                           $('#a_div_id').html(data); //put the post data on a div content
                             $('#a_div_id_that_was_hidden').show();

                    }

            });

        };
```

Giving a onclick event to the variable o a ul, button,li or whatever you want will make it work.
Hope it helps

Comment: Regarding your question to use ajax and jquery...
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
between your <head></head>
then put the script I have posted on your javascript.js file and then call to the script whit a onclick handler... by examle

<li id="something" onclick="myfunction();"><a href="#hiddendiv_id">Hiddendiv_filled!</a></li>